# Discrete Cauchy integral formula : The interior values are always convex combinations of exterior values for harmonic functions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, convex-analysis

Let $T={\mathbb Z}^2$. For $t=(x,y)\in T$, the **neighborhood** 
$N(t)$ of $t$ is the four-point set $\lbrace x\pm 1;y\pm 1\rbrace$. A map
$f:T \to {\mathbb R}$ is **harmonic** iff $4f(t)=\sum_{s\in N(t)}f(s)$ for
any $s\in t$.

Let $A\subseteq {\mathbb Z}^2$. For $a\in A$, say that $a$ is **interior** if $N(a)\subseteq A$. Denoting by $I(A)$ the set of interior points in $A$, $a\in A$ is a **limit point** if $a\not\in I(A)$ but $N(a)\cap I(A)\neq \emptyset$. Note that some points in $A$ may be neither interior nor limit points (e.g. when $A$ is a singleton).

My question is, is it always true that given a finite $A\subseteq {\mathbb Z}^2$ and given an interior point $a\in A$, if we denote by $L_1,L_2,L_3,\ldots,L_t$
the limit points of $A$, then there are nonnegative coefficients 
$c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_t$, depending only on $A$ and $a$, with
$\sum_{k}c_k=1$, such that $f(a)=\sum_{k}c_kf(L_k)$ for any harmonic $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll say that a function is harmonic on a set $A$ if $4f(t)=\sum_{s\in N(t)}f(s)$ holds for all $t\in I(A)$.

**Claim 1**. *If a harmonic function $h$ on $A$ is nonnegative at all limit points of $A$, then it is nonnegative at all interior points of $A$.*

*Proof*. Suppose to the contrary that $h(c)<0$ for some $c\in I(A)$. Let $M$ be the minimum of $h$ on $I(A)$, and let $B=\{x\in I(A): h(x)=M\}$. Since $B$ is not all of $\mathbb Z^2$, there is a point $b\in B$ that neighbors a point $b'\notin B$. The harmonic property implies $h(b')=M$. Therefore, $b'\notin I(A)$. Since $b'$ neighbors $b$, it is a limit point of $A$. But then $h(b')\ge 0$, a contradiction. $\qquad \Box$

**Corollary:** if $h=0$ at all limit points of $A$, then it is zero at all interior points of $A$.

**Claim 2**. *For each $i=1,\dots,t$ there exists a  harmonic function $\omega_i$ on  $A$ such that $\omega_i(L_j)=\delta_{ij}$ (Kronecker delta). This function $\omega_i$ satisfies $0\le \omega_i \le 1$ in $I(A)$. Its values in $I(A)$ are uniquely determined, even if $\omega_i$ itself is not.*

*Proof*. The uniqueness part follows from Corollary. To show existence, define the *energy* of function $f$ as $$E(f) = \sum_{\{a,b\}\cap I(A)\ne\varnothing, \ b\in N(a) } |f(a)-f(b)|^2$$
Let $\omega_i:A\to \mathbb R$ be a function of smallest energy with prescribed values at limit points (such a function exists by compactness). Then $\omega_i$ is harmonic on $A$, for otherwise we could decrease its energy by redefining it at some interior point. The inequality $0\le \omega_i\le 1$ holds by  Claim 1. $\qquad \Box$

Now we can let $c_i=\omega_i(a)$ and conclude.

Comment: The energy argument is magic.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Known as the [Dirichlet principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_principle).

Comment: By the way, I think that the $c_i$ are always nonzero, do you have a proof of that also ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy You'd need some connectedness assumptions on $A$ for that. Otherwise $A$ could be a disjoint union of two squares; then the limit points of one square have zero contribution to the interior points of the other square. But if some connectedness is in place, one can rework the proof of Claim 1 to show that $\omega_i>0$ at all interior points, by arguing with the set $\{x\in I(A):\omega_i(x)\}$ along the same lines. .. By the way, the key term is *discrete harmonic measure*.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy There's a typo in my previous comment: I meant $\{x\in I(A):\omega_i(x)=0\}$.